# Efficient way of performing groupby and bfill on very large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pyspark

Is there any efficient way to do groupby and perform forward fill in a large dataframe?
I have a dataframe with 2768186062 rows which looks like this:

```
 email                    email_created_date              country
a01423240@itesm.mx       2021-03-27 00:44:49+00:00          NaN
a01423240@itesm.mx       2022-01-14 16:27:18+00:00          IND
aalvarezleo@gmail.com    2021-05-14 13:24:15+00:00          NaN
aalvarezleo@gmail.com    2021-09-16 16:09:45+00:00          IND
acabazot@gmail.com       2021-03-27 00:38:37+00:00          NaN
acabazot@gmail.com       2022-01-14 12:25:28+00:00          IND
alt_wwe@hotmail.com      2022-09-22 22:08:50+00:00          NaN
alt_wwe@hotmail.com      2022-09-22 22:11:51+00:00          CA
```

I wanted to do backward fill in the column country based on the same email. So the expected output looks like:

```
  email                    email_created_date              country
a01423240@itesm.mx       2021-03-27 00:44:49+00:00          IND
a01423240@itesm.mx       2022-01-14 16:27:18+00:00          IND
aalvarezleo@gmail.com    2021-05-14 13:24:15+00:00          IND
aalvarezleo@gmail.com    2021-09-16 16:09:45+00:00          IND
acabazot@gmail.com       2021-03-27 00:38:37+00:00          IND
acabazot@gmail.com       2022-01-14 12:25:28+00:00          IND
alt_wwe@hotmail.com      2022-09-22 22:08:50+00:00          CA
alt_wwe@hotmail.com      2022-09-22 22:11:51+00:00          CA
```

I have done it using the following code:

```
 dt1[['country']]=(dt1
                  .sort_values(['email','email_created_date'])
                  .groupby(['email'], as_index=False)[['country']].fillna(method='bfill'))
```

but it taking a lot of time more than an hour to exceute the above code as the dataframe is very big.
Could anyone suggest/help to perform the above operation in the most efficient way? I want to make sure that I am being as efficient as possible (it took my computer a long time to read and consolidate all of these files into memory).
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be faster to avoid sorting and grouping the data at all.  If you can safely assume that each `email` corresponds to only one `country`, then you can construct a mapping from email to country and use that to assign all `country` values.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """\
email                    email_created_date                 country
a01423240@itesm.mx       2021-03-27 00:44:49+00:00          NaN
a01423240@itesm.mx       2022-01-14 16:27:18+00:00          IND
aalvarezleo@gmail.com    2021-05-14 13:24:15+00:00          NaN
aalvarezleo@gmail.com    2021-09-16 16:09:45+00:00          IND
acabazot@gmail.com       2021-03-27 00:38:37+00:00          NaN
acabazot@gmail.com       2022-01-14 12:25:28+00:00          IND
alt_wwe@hotmail.com      2022-09-22 22:08:50+00:00          NaN
alt_wwe@hotmail.com      2022-09-22 22:11:51+00:00          CA
"""

# Load the example data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s\s+', parse_dates=True, engine='python', dtype={'country': 'category'})

# Construct a lookup table from email -> country
valid_rows = df.loc[~df['country'].isnull(), ['email', 'country']]
country_mapping = valid_rows.drop_duplicates('email').set_index('email')['country']

# Apply the lookup table.
df['country'] = df['email'].map(country_mapping)

print(df)
```

```
                   email         email_created_date country
0     a01423240@itesm.mx  2021-03-27 00:44:49+00:00     IND
1     a01423240@itesm.mx  2022-01-14 16:27:18+00:00     IND
2  aalvarezleo@gmail.com  2021-05-14 13:24:15+00:00     IND
3  aalvarezleo@gmail.com  2021-09-16 16:09:45+00:00     IND
4     acabazot@gmail.com  2021-03-27 00:38:37+00:00     IND
5     acabazot@gmail.com  2022-01-14 12:25:28+00:00     IND
6    alt_wwe@hotmail.com  2022-09-22 22:08:50+00:00      CA
7    alt_wwe@hotmail.com  2022-09-22 22:11:51+00:00      CA
```